# how to use SAS array for counting and averaging by group?

Tags: sas

I have a following dataset :

CustID  NGIF    RAMN    RFA1

2001      6     52      1
2002      1     23      1
2003      8     99      1
2004      20    100     4
2005      11    114     3
2006      9     138     1
2007      7     105     3
2008      15    190     2
2009      27    297     1
2010      22    207     1
2011      19    171     2

I want to compute for each RFA1 level (which is 1-4), the average (Total RAMN for a RFA1 level / total count of that RFA1 level) using arrays. Without arrays, If I split and do, I get result for individual level. Following is the code:

```
enter code here

data averagetotalcatlog (drop=CustomerID NGIF RAMN);
set Catlog;
    by RFA1;
where RFA1 = 1;
if First.RFA1 then TotalRAMN = 0 & TotalCust = 0 & Average = 0;
TotalCust + 1;
TotalRAMN + RAMN;
if Last.RFA1;
Average = TotalRAMN / TotalCust;
run;
```

My problem is How do I write this code for all the 4 levels of RFA1 using Arrays ??

Comment: What do you think those `&` are doing? Probably not what they actually are doing.

Comment: Further, why do you want to do this with arrays?  `PROC MEANS` will happily do this work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Joe. I have tried this with PROC MEANS and yes they are doing what is required. But I am learning SAS and fresher to it, and want to learn arrays too. Hence, I am trying to solve it using Arrays. 
I think with '&' I am initializing three variables in one sentence based on the if condition. Please pardon me for my ignorance and let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: `&` doesn't work that way.  I suggest an intro SAS class to learn how to do things like this; you're jumping in too far before you learn basic things like that.

Comment: @ Joe: Thank you for your suggestion regarding &, it helped me to reach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

SAS uses arrays to work with data in "wide form"

If you transposed your data with proc transpose you could manipulate the data using arrays.

```
data temp;
input CustID NGIF RAMN RFA1;
datalines;
2001 6 52 1
2002 1 23 1
2003 8 99 1
2004 20 100 4
2005 11 114 3
2006 9 138 1
2007 7 105 3
2008 15 190 2
2009 27 297 1
2010 22 207 1
2011 19 171 2
;
run;

proc sort data=temp; by RFA1; run;

proc transpose data=temp out=temp2;
by RFA1;
var RAMN;
run;

data temp3;
    set temp2;
        SUM_RAMN = 0; CNT_RAMN = 0;
        array COL_{6} COL1-COL6;
        do I = 1 to 6;
            if COL_{I} ne . then do;
                SUM_RAMN = SUM_RAMN + COL_{I};
                CNT_RAMN = CNT_RAMN + 1;
            end;
        end;
        AVG_RAMN = SUM_RAMN/CNT_RAMN;
    keep RFA1 AVG_RAMN;
run;
```

However, as it was previously noted... this would be a very difficult solution to something that could be solved in SAS with easier methods than arrays.

Comment: Hello JJFord3, thank you for your answer. Yes, it is difficult to use array n getting this result. I also have worked out a code.


    proc sort data = Catlog;
 by RFA1;
    run;

    data averagetotalcatlog (drop=CustomerID NGIF RAMN LASG LASD     RFA2 Money Order);
    set Catlog;
 by RFA1;
    array RFA1_ar (3) TotalCust TotalRAMN Average;
    if First.RFA1 then TotalCust = 0;
    TotalCust + 1;
    if First.RFA1 then TotalRAMN = 0;
    TotalRAMN + RAMN;
    if Last.RFA1;
    Average = TotalRAMN / TotalCust;
    drop i;
    run;

I dont know if its valid use of array, but it worked for me.